# How to print in American "$" currency on this debug?

Tags: apex

Is anyone familiar with printing clean currency using Apex? Instead of displaying 110000.0, I wanted to print $110,000.00

```
integer salary=100000;
decimal bonus,salaryAfterBonus;
if(salary>=150000)
{
    bonus=15;
}
else if(salary>=120000)
{
    bonus=12;
}
else if(salary>=100000)
{
    bonus=10;
}
salaryAfterBonus=salary+(salary*(bonus/100));
system.debug('Salary is: '+salary); //prints: Salary is: 100000
system.debug('Bonus is: '+bonus+'%'); //prints: Bonus is: 10%
system.debug('Salary after bonus is: '+salaryAfterBonus); //prints: Salary after bonus is: 110000.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use format function to format your numbers but it wont put currency symbol you will have to append it.

For example

```
Integer a = 140000;
System.debug('$'+ a.format().contains('.')?a.format():(a.format()+'.00')); // $140,000.00
```

If changing data type is not problem salary should be Decimal rather than integer and same would be done as below

```
Decimal a = 12345.42 ;
System.debug(a.setScale(2).format()); // 12,345.42
```

Remember format function works on the basis of locale of your user

Comment: This would be better done using `Decimal` instead of `Integer`, setting the number of decimal places with `setScale(2)`, I suggest. Obviously the hard-coded "$" in the output prevents this working in a multi-currency org. Oddly, there is apparently a `System` type, `System.Currency`, with a `newInstance(value, isoCode)` factory method and a `formatAmount()` method... at least this class shows up in Illuminated Cloud. Unfortunately trying to use it generates the error "Type is not visible: CURRENCY". This would have been ideal!

Comment: Yep you are correct , ideally this needs to be done with decimal and set scale. I'll add to answer for multi currency  I was thinking to may be maintain a map with symbol and currency iso code in apex

Comment: awesome, that worked.

Comment: This did the trick;

.setScale(2).format()